# Sorting the results of _.countBy

Tags: sorting, collections, underscore.js

I have a collection (Products) and I use `_.countBy` like this :

```
var totalByBrand = _.countBy(result, "Brand");
```

and I have this result :

```
{
    'Brand 1 ' : 5,
    'Brand 2 ' : 45,
    'Brand 3 ' : 2,
    ...
    'Brand 99 ' : 25
}
```

I try to sort this result to obtain that :

```
{
    'Brand 3 ' : 2,
    'Brand 1 ' : 5,
    'Brand 99 ' : 25,
    ...
    'Brand 2 ' : 45
}
```

Is it possible with `_.sortBy()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties order cannot be guaranteed in JavaScript [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) and that means you can't sort them.

You would have to use a different structure, maybe a list of objects like `{brand: ..., count: ...}` and sort on on `count`. For example

```
var totalByBrand = _.countBy(products, 'Brand');

var sorted = _.chain(totalByBrand).
    map(function(cnt, brand) {
        return {
            brand: brand,
            count: cnt
        }
    })
    .sortBy('count')
    .value();
```

And a demo

```js
var products = [
    {Brand: "Brand 1", id: 1},
    {Brand: "Brand 1", id: 2},
    {Brand: "Brand 2", id: 3},
    {Brand: "Brand 3", id: 4},
    {Brand: "Brand 3", id: 5},
    {Brand: "Brand 1", id: 6},
];

var totalByBrand = _.countBy(products, 'Brand');
    
var sorted = _.chain(totalByBrand).
    map(function(cnt, brand) {
        return {
            brand: brand,
            count: cnt
        }
    }).sortBy('count')
    .value();
    
console.dir(
    sorted
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very thanks for you answer ! I try it this afternoon and i will   keep in touch!.